# ctypes.c_long(0L) for Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, python-2.x

I am transitioning from Python 2x to Python 3x and I am using ctypes. On Python 2x, the following code ran perfectly:

```
ctypes.c_long(0L)
```

However, 0L is an invalid syntax for Python 3x. Is there a way for me to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the L at the end. Just do `ctypes.c_long(0)`. As I understand, this is because Python 3x [maps](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) `c_long` to Python type `int`, whereas Python 2x [allowed](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) `int` or `long`. This, in turn, comes from the fact that there is [no more](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers) a built-in `long` type.

Comment: You don't need the 0 either. It's just `ctypes.c_long()`. ctypes zeros all buffers that it allocates.

Comment: Yes. However, one could use it in the above manner with a non-zero value.